# Stylus throws annoying errors in PhpStorm console

Tags: phpstorm, webstorm, stylus

I use **Stylus** to build css in **PhpStorm**. It works fine. But there is a small problem with console.

When I type tag or class name and then press enter the annoying console appears again and again with parse error:

http://s24.postimg.org/nbljrdo11/stylus.png

And if i type .very-long-class-name it appears at least 3 times without giving me a chance to finish.

I can disable the console completely but maybe there is a way to solve it?

Comment: Disable `Immediate file synchronisation` in your File Watcher settings.

Comment: It's almost the same as disabling console. Parser starts after too long a delay. Is that time more configurable?

Comment: There is no configurable delay: it's either immediate (approx 1 sec delay) or (when the aforementioned option disabled) after file is saved. So .. if you do not want to disable that option, then type your ".very-long-class-name" faster (with no delays) .. or press "Save" more often.